# Could anyone suggest good plugins / api's etc. to add HTML5/CSS3 support to old browsers?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I was thinking id there are any javascript or other type plugins that will add css3 and html5 support to old browsers (especialy ie). I couldn't find any on google. The thing is that I really enjoy using css3 for styling instead of using images etc... I't all good, but as you know it doesn't look good in old browsers, so I was wondering if there is anything that could be done here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this: http://www.modernizr.com/

Comment: or more to be more specific here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills

Comment: Mordernizr is used to detect browser-support for CSS3 and HTML5, it does not add support to older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

There's a list on the modernizr page with many so called polyfills for all the new browser technologies: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills